# WPF GridControl : Tick checkbox automatically when row is focused and untick on unfocus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Grid Control with some columns. I also have a checkedit column with a checkbox.

What I wish to accomplish is when the user selects a row ( clicks a row ) in the grid control, I want the checkbox to become checked automatically.

And then when the user clicks a different row, the checkbox in the newly selected row would become checked and the checkbox in the previously selected row would become unchecked.

The checkboxes are disabled so that the user isn't required to click the actual checkbox itself but anywhere in the same row.

Basically the checkbox is to act as an indicator to show the user exactly which row they clicked on so they know they have the right record when they click a delete button for example.

Hope this is descriptive enough.

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry all.. Im using a DevExpress datagrid, it doesn't seem to allow the properties in the below answers..

```
<!-- DX Grid with charges  -->
    <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" FocusableChanged="FinanceOperationsGrid_FocusableChanged" Grid.RowSpan="6" DataSource="{Binding FinanceOperations}" x:Name="FinanceOperationsGrid">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Width="20" AllowEditing="False" ShowInColumnChooser="False" AllowAutoFilter="False" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Width="20" UnboundType="Boolean" AllowEditing="True" ShowInColumnChooser="False" AllowAutoFilter="False">
                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="chkSelectedRow" IsThreeState="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        </dxe:CheckEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Created" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="Created" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Operation type" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="OperationDisplay" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Amount" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="Amount">
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxe:SpinEditSettings MaskType="Numeric" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" Mask="c2" />
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Description" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="Description" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView BestFitArea="Header" BestFitMode="AllRows" AutoWidth="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" MultiSelectMode="Row" NavigationStyle="Row" 
                           RowStyle="{StaticResource AccountHistoryRowStyle}" DataRowTemplate="{StaticResource ChargeRowTemplate}" FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedOperation, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <dxg:TableView.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="{dxgt:RowIndicatorThemeKey ResourceKey=FocusedIconTemplate}">
                        <Canvas Width="20" Height="20">
                            <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" Height="20" />
                            <Polygon Points="5,5 5,15 10,10" Fill="Blue" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TableView.Resources>
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: It would be relatively easier to help you if you show the Datagrid and the SelectedItem(if handled) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have to define a property of type of collection bound to your grid and SelectedItem of the datagrid should be bound to this property. So whenever selected row changes setter of this property is triggered. within setter set the property bound to the check box to appropriate value so that checkbox will be ticked.

> XAML

```
 <DataGrid  Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMilestoneItem}" Name="MilestoneGrid"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MilestoneGridData}"
```

> ViewModel

```
public MilestoneItemViewModel SelectedMilestoneItem
{
    get
    {
        return selectedMilestoneItem;
    }

    set
    {
        selectedMilestoneItem = value;
        selectedMilestoneItem.CheckBoxValue = true;
        NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedMilestoneItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Selected answer as it answered my original question closest to my needs. Thanks guys for your time to answer my question . Much appreciated. Vote also given to both

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectedCellsChanged` event, and in your eventhandler iterate across your items and set the selection boolean to False (make sure that it notifies via NotifyPropertyChanged or is a Dependency property so the UI would be aware of the change)
after that,use the sender as a Grid and iterate through his SelectedItems and set the selected boolean to True:

**.xaml:**

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Selected}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public ObservableCollection<NameItem> MyItems { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<NameItem>();
        MyItems.Add(new NameItem() { Name = "A" });
        MyItems.Add(new NameItem() { Name = "B" });
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in MyItems)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
        }
        var datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (datagrid != null)
            foreach (var item in datagrid.SelectedItems)
            {
                var nameItem = item as NameItem;
                if (nameItem != null) nameItem.Selected = true;
            }
    }

}
public class NameItem : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Selected", typeof (Boolean), typeof (NameItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(Boolean)));

    public Boolean Selected
    {
        get { return (Boolean) GetValue(SelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedProperty, value); }
    }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```